# Einzahl oder Mehrzahl verwenden, wenn beides im Satz vorher vorkommt?

Tags: grammar

Ich habe folgenden Satz:

> Physik und ihre Anwendungen zur Lösung quantitativer Problemstellung
>   sind meine Leidenschaft.

Nun meine Frage, ob man hier *ist* oder *sind* verwendet? Da es sich ja eigentlich auf Physik bezieht, deshalb würde man *ist* nehmen. Die Anwendungen sind jedoch Mehrzahl, weshalb man *sind* nehmen sollte, was ist richtig?

Comment: Wenn du den Satz wiefolg im Kopf liest, dann verwendest du "ist", sonst "sind": "Physik–einschließlich ihrer Anwendungen zur Lösung quantitativer Problemstellungen–ist meine Leidenschaft.

Answer (score 6):

Die Lösung lautet:

### Plural

Denn schon dieser Satz verlangt nach dem Plural:

> Die Physik (singular) und die Anwendung (singular) **sind** (plural) **meine Leidenschaften** (plural).

Es heißt ja auch:

> Wasser und Honig **sind Flüssigkeiten**.

Falsch wäre: "Wasser und Honig **ist eine Flüssigkeit**."
Genauso falsch ist "Die Physik und die Anwendung **ist meine Leidenschaft**."

Denn immer wenn im Subjekt *mehrere* Dinge stehen, ist das ganze Subjekt ein Plural-Ding. Das ist immer der Fall wenn einer dieser Fälle zutrifft:

1. Im Subjekt steht ein einziges Nomen im Plural.
2. Im Subjekt steht eine Aufzählung mehrerer Nomen (egal ob die einzelnen Elemente der Aufzählung im Singular oder Plural stehen).

Korrektes Beispiel für Fall 1: "Die Autos sind schnell." Falsch wäre: "Die Autos ist schnell."

Korrektes Beispiel für Fall 2: "Der BMW und der Audi sind schnell." Falsch wäre: "Der BMW und der Audi ist schnell."

**auch das Objekt muss im Pural stehen, nicht nur das Prädikat.**
Dein Satz enthielt auch noch einen zweiten Fehler. Die Physik und ihre Anwendungen sind nicht deine Leidenschaft (singular) sondern deine *Leidenschaften* (Plural).

> Physik und ihre Anwendungen zur Lösung quantitativer Problemstellung **sind meine Leidenschaften**.

---

Eigentlich auch falsch ist dieser Satz (auf das "eigentlich" komme ich gleich zu sprechen):

```
Marmor, Stein und Eisen *bricht*.
```

richtig wäre:

> Marmor, Stein und Eisen **brechen**.

Wegen dieses Grammatik-Fehlers hatte vor knapp 50 Jahren das gleichnamige Lied von Drafi Deutscher lange Zeit Sendeverbot im Bayerischen Rundfunk. Allerdings entspricht dieser Satz genau einem Ausnahme-Muster, nämlich dem *Singuar Materialis*. Näheres dazu steht hier: http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singularis_materialis

Doch sind weder "Physik" noch "ihre Anwendungen" Materialien. Daher gibt es hier keine Ausnahme.

Comment: Die Erklärung mit dem Singularis Materialis ist sehr gut, aber der Schluß ist m.E. falsch. `Das Wasser und der daraus gebrühte Kaffee ist vergiftet` kann ich durchaus sagen, wenn Kaffee und Wasser nicht mehr getrennt vorliegen, sondern alles Wasser in Kaffee übergegangen ist. Ebenso kann ich sagen `Die PHysik und deren Anwendung ist mein Plaisier`. Entscheidend ist nicht die Materialiät (Glück ist auch kein Material, oder gleich und gleich).

Comment: @userunknown Tut mir leid, aber beide von dir vorgebrachten Beispiele sind falsch. Richtig ist `Das Wasser und der Kaffee SIND vergiftet.` Dabei ist egal, ob der Kaffee aus genau diesem Wasser gebrüht wurde oder aus etwas anderem. Dein zweites Beispiel muss so lauten: `Die Physik und deren Anwendung SIND deine PLÄSIERE.` In beiden Beispielen wäre die Einzahl falsch. Übrigens: "Das Päsier" schreibt man entweder (eingedeutscht) "Pläsier" (mit ä und langem ie) oder (französisch) "Plaisir" (mit ai und kurzem i). Vorzuziehen ist die eingedeutschte Version.

Comment: Seltsam - heute kommt es mir auch falsch vor. Was aber ist mit dem Material "Gleich" oder "Glück"?

Comment: @userunknown Gute Frage. Ich habe auf der Diskussionsseite des Wikipedia-Artikels einen entsprechenden Hinweis gepostet.

Answer (score 2):

Ein solches `[x] und [y] machen [z]` kann man auf zwei verschiedene Arten interpretieren:

1. `[x] macht [z] und [y] macht [z]`. Dann ist eine Zusammenziehung beider Sätze, analog zum Ausklammern in der Mathematik. In diesem Fall können nur die tatsächlich gleichen Komponenten ausgeklammert werden. Die richtige Umsetzung in deinem Beispiel wäre:

   > „Die Physik *ist* und ihre Anwendungen zur Lösung quantitativer Problemstellungen *sind* meine Leidenschaft.“
   >   Der ausgeklammert Teil ist also nur `meine Leidenschaft`.
2. `[x] und [y]` ist zusammen das Subjekt des Satzes. Dann ist es ein Plural und das Verb muss entsprechend konjugiert werden. Die richtige Umsetzung in deinem Beispiel wäre:

> „Die Physik und ihre Anwendungen zur Lösung quantitativer Problemstellungen *sind* meine Leidenschaft.

Answer (score 1):

Beispiel:

```
Physik und ihre Anwendungen zur Lösung quantitativer Problemstellung sind meine Leidenschaft.
```

Der Nebensatz von der Lösung quantitativer Problemstellungen trägt zur Fragestellung nichts bei, außer von der Fragestellung abzulenken und wird besser geopfert.

```
Physik und ihre Anwendungen sind meine Leidenschaft.
```

Hier fehlt ein 'Die' vor der Physik.

```
Die Physik und ihre Anwendungen sind meine Leidenschaft.
```

Das kann man schreiben, denn

```
Der Kater Mikesch und die 3 Hamster sind meine Haustiere.
```

ist ein Satz über insgesamt 4 Tiere, die erst recht Plural sind. Aber die Physik als eine Lehre kommt auch mit einer Einzahl in der Anwendung aus, was nicht heißt, dass es nur eine Anwendung der Physik gibt, sondern dass man von der generellen Idee des Anwendens spricht, wie von der Physik:

```
Die Physik und deren Anwendung ist meine Leidenschaft.
```

Wenn die Physik und ihre Anwendung für Dich eine Einheit bildet, dann kann man m.E. auch in Einzahl sprechen. Etwa Du hast ein britisches Landgut geerbt, und täglich, zum 16 Uhr Tee, ziehst Du Dich in Dein Labor zurück, und der Physik und ihrer Anwendung zu huldigen.

```
Die Physik und ihre Anwendung interessieren Dich brennend. Montags bis freitags studierst Du erstere in der Bibliothek, aber das Wochenende krönt der Ausflug ins Labor.
```

Siehe dazu auch den von [Hubert Schönlast beigetragenen Link.](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singularis_materialis)

Ansonsten bleibt darauf hinzuweisen, dass nicht jeder Satz so konstruiert werden muss, dass ein einzelnes Verb zwei nicht harmonisierbare Teilsätze behandelt. Oft lohnt es sich einen Schritt vom Satz zurückzutreten, und einen ganz anderen Lösungsweg zu suchen.

```
Die Physik ist meine Leidenschaft und ihre Anwendungen sind mein finanzieller Ruin.
```