# "Wird oder werden" in A sowie B?

Tags: grammar, grammatical-number

Diese Sache hier macht mich schon ganz verrückt. Verwendet man hier "wird" oder "werden"?

> In der vorliegenden Arbeit wird/werden das Design des Menschen sowie die entdeckten Gliedmaßen, die nach dem Anfassen abfielen, vorgestellt.

Das ist nur ein Beispielsatz. Also nicht lachen :-)

> [google suchlink: wird (1,4 Millionen Ergebnisse)](https://www.google.de/#q=%22In+der+vorliegenden+arbeit+wird+das+*+sowie%22)
>
> [google suchlink: werden (9 Ergebnisse)](https://www.google.de/#q=%22In+der+vorliegenden+arbeit+werden+das+*+sowie%22)

Comment: Die Entscheidung liegt in der Frage, ob es um *eine* Sache (das Design des Menschen) oder um *zwei* Sachen (das Design des Menschen + die entdeckten Gliedmaßen) geht.

Comment: Da "die Gliedmaßen" in der Mehrzahl stehen, gibt es *in diesem* Fall keinen Spielraum.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Die richtige Antwort ist:

### werden (Plural)

Das Subjekt deines Satzes lautet:
`das Design des Menschen sowie die entdeckten Gliedmaßen, die nach dem Anfassen abfielen`

Lässt man die für die Fragestellung grammatikalisch unwichtigen Dinge weg, sieht dein Satz so aus:

> Es werden das Design und die Gliedmaßen vorgestellt.

Das Subjekt dieses verkürzten Satzes ist:
`das Design und die Gliedmaßen`.

Es sind also **mehrere** Dinge im Subjekt enthalten (nämlich ein Design und mehrere Gliedmaßen). Das Subjekt ist eine Aufzählung und verkörpert daher einen Plural. Somit muss auch das Prädikat im Plural stehen.

Hier gilt alles, was ich auch schon hier in meiner Antwort zu einer ähnlichen Frage gesagt habe: [Einzahl oder Mehrzahl verwenden, wenn beides im Satz vorher vorkommt?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/12145/einzahl-oder-mehrzahl-verwenden-wenn-beides-im-satz-vorher-vorkommt)

Comment: Hi Hubert, danke! Ich habe jetzt folgendes gefunden: http://www.canoo.net/services/OnlineGrammar/Wort/Verb/Numerus-Person/ProblemNum.html#Anchor-49575 <-- dort wird gesagt, dass "wird" üblicher ist, weil die Subjektteile dem Verb folgen. Würde ich den Satz umstellen, würde es werden heißen.

Answer (score 1):

Because the group in question – `das Design des Menschen sowie die entdeckten Gliedmaßen, […]` – uses `sowie` instead of `und` it cannot be interpreted as a short form of two combined sentences like in [this German.Stackexchange post](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/12145/einzahl-oder-mehrzahl-verwenden-wenn-beides-im-satz-vorher-vorkommt/12146#12146).

The only grammatically possible interpretation is, that this group is *the* subject of the sentence. As it consists of several parts, it's plural and consequently the predicate has to be in plural as well.

> In der vorliegenden Arbeit *werden* das Design des Menschen sowie die entdeckten Gliedmaßen, die nach dem Anfassen abfielen, vorgestellt.

Comment: Hi, thanks. I found following http://www.canoo.net/services/OnlineGrammar/Wort/Verb/Numerus-Person/ProblemNum.html#Anchor-49575 and it says, that "wird" is more common.

Comment: @user1091344 I'm not a grammar nazi, but using singular here is lazy as hell.

Answer (score -1):

It depends. Are you talking about one thing, or multiple things? Personally I'd use *werden* in the case of your example.

Comment: No, it doesn't depend. It *is* several things.